# Unable to select item from dropdown when row is draggable (ng-drag) in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="dr in vm.funds" style="cursor: move;" 
    ng-drag="true" 
    ng-drag-data="dr" 
    ng-drop="true" 
    ng-drop-success="vm.onDropComplete($index, $data, $event)">
    <td>{{dr.fundName}}</td>
    <td>{{dr.tickerId}}</td>
    <td>{{dr.assetClassName}}</td>
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" ng-disabled="false" ng-model="dr.action" ng-options="v as v.actionDescription for v in dr.actions track by v.actionId"></select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm unable to select item from dropdown on draggable row. It looks like ng-drag prevents the click events, even if we put input text which is also not allowing to enter any text.

Kindly help me to resolve this

Comment: Please add the code work till you finished now.

Comment: create a plunker with your codes